# Apollo CLIError: Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project"

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

I am trying to get api-types for the project that is running Apollo server since years. But now when I run command `apollo client:codegen api-types  --includes=src/**/*.tsx  --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/graphql --target=typescript --globalTypesFile=src/api-types/globalTypes.ts` I get below error:

```
 Warning: apollo update available from 2.33.4 to 2.33.9.
  ⠸ Loading Apollo Project
    Generating query files
CLIError: Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project": Error: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
 at Object.error (/workApp/node_modules/@oclif/errors/lib/index.js:26:15)
    at Generate.error (/workApp/node_modules/@oclif/command/lib/command.js:60:23)
    at OclifLoadingHandler.showError (/workApp/node_modules/apollo/lib/OclifLoadingHandler.js:29:22)
    at OclifLoadingHandler.handle (/workApp/node_modules/apollo/lib/OclifLoadingHandler.js:14:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  oclif: { exit: 2 },
  ✖ Loading Apollo Project
    → Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "Unnamed Project": Error:
…
    Generating query files
 ›   Error: Error initializing Apollo GraphQL project "Unnamed Project":
 ›    Error: Error in "Loading schema for Unnamed Project": Error: 
 ›   ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
```

I looked a few Stackoveflow posts and tried this command too: `apollo schema:download --endpoint=http://localhost:4000/graphql schema.json`

But that also gives me below error:

```
 ✔ Loading Apollo Project
  ✖ Saving schema to schema.json
    → ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 500
    Error: ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 
    500
```

Any suggestion to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Along with your endpoint url ,if needed pass Authorization token in the header options .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).